# How to use substr function to multiple variables and write it a csv file in R?

Tags: r, csv

have a data frame , let's say mtcars and i want to extract different values from different variables and finally  i want to form a CSV data frame in R .

data

```
   mpg      cyl   disp  hp 
   21.0   6160.0  110   3.90 
   21.0   6160.0  110   3.90 
   22.8   4108.0  93    3.85 
   21.4   6258.0  110   3.08 
   18.7   8360.0  175   3.15
```

So from mpg variable i want to extract 1st 2 letters and from cyl i want to extract first 3 numbers..... e.t.c, for that i have a key as follows

keyfile

```
 header  startkey endkey
 mpg     0        2
 cyl     0        3
 disp    1        2
 hp      2        4
```

Expected output

```
   mpg  cyl   disp   hp 
   21   616   11    .90 
   21   616   11    .90 
   22   410   93    .85 
   21   625   11    .08 
   18   836   17    .15
```

Tried:

```
vars = unique(as.character(keyfile$header))
start_keys = keyfile$startkey
end_keys = keyfile$endkey

for(i in 1:length(vars)){
for (j in 1:length(start_key)){
for(k in 1:length(end_key)){
data = substr(data$i,j,k)
filename = paste(deparse(substitute(output_data)), ".csv",sep="")
write.csv(data,file = filename)
}
}
}
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to extract the substring of each column in 'data' based on the corresponding 'startkey', 'endkey' from 'keyfile'

```
data[] <- Map(substr, data[keyfile$header], keyfile$startkey, keyfile$endkey)
```

If we wanted to convert to `numeric`

```
data[] <- Map(function(...) as.numeric(substr(...)), 
               data[keyfile$header], keyfile$startkey, keyfile$endkey)
data
#  mpg cyl disp   hp
#1  21 616   11 0.90
#2  21 616   11 0.90
#3  22 410   93 0.85
#4  21 625   11 0.08
#5  18 836   17 0.15
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7), cyl = c(6160, 
6160, 4108, 6258, 8360), disp = c(110L, 110L, 93L, 110L, 175L
), hp = c(3.9, 3.9, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15)), .Names = c("mpg", "cyl", 
"disp", "hp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

keyfile <- structure(list(header = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp"), startkey = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L), endkey = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 4L)), .Names = c("header", 
"startkey", "endkey"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```